# What would be the best way to store traceroute results?

Tags: database, traceroute

One traceroute record may include :

- Timestamp. Milliseconds resolution.
- Variable number of hops.
- Each hops contains, ip address, hostname and rtt.
- Overall results e.g. successful, network unreachable, timed out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database. You could use SQLite if you don't want to run a database server.

More details:
There is this nice little sqlite addon for firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager

That should help you set things up. I would create a field for each of the values I want to store and on for the entire result perhaps and an primary key "id" field.

Getting your data into the database would be least trivial part. If your running linux, you could write a bash shell script that captures the output of traceroute and calls a PHP shell script which inserts the data into the DB. Of course you can use Python or any language you like which supports your DB.

Comment: That's what i thought. But how do i setup the tables structure ?

Comment: I've added some more specifics. Hopefully that will get you on your way.